# Using information from outside class: Prisoner's Dilemma

Tags: java, class, boolean

This week my class is working on a lab called the Prisoner's Dilemma. The idea is two convicts, questioned in separate rooms, have the option to COOPERATE with each other or to DEFECT and rat the other out. 
Our job is to write up strategies using this skeleton:

```
 package specs;

    public interface Strategy {
        public void opponentMove(boolean isDefecting);
        public boolean isDefecting();
    }
```

The strategies are then run through a simulator against those made by other students.

My query is this: how can I make my strategy remember its last move, or its opponent's last move. 
The way I see it, the only thing that the strategy class knows is that it is either C or D, and it has an opponent, somewhere, that is also either C or D.

Comment: Hint:  You'll need a concrete implementation of this Strategy interface in order to track this information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very simple, in the case of TitForTat the two methods become simple getters and setters of the `lastMove` state variable.

```
public class TitForTat implements Strategy {
  private boolean lastMove;

  public void opponentMove(boolean isDefecting) {
     lastMove = isDefecting;
  }

  public boolean isDefecting() {
    return lastMove;
  }
}
```

I hope you can extrapolate from this to other strategies.